# How assembly groupby datetime by week

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a **date** column formatted like this `2019-08-01 00:03:43` I need to have an extra column that groups this data by week and name.

Data:

```
cw = 

lead_date              name
2019-08-01 00:03:43    a
2019-08-01 00:00:00    b
2019-08-01 00:03:49    c
2019-08-31 23:42:04    a
2019-08-31 23:42:04    a
2019-08-31 23:42:04    c
2019-08-31 23:42:04    a
```

What I done:

```
df= cw

df["_id"] = pd.to_datetime(cw["lead_date"])


df['date_minus_time'] = df["_id"].apply( lambda df : datetime.datetime(year=df.year, month=df.month, day=df.day))


df.set_index(df["date_minus_time"],inplace=True)

df['week'] =  df['_id'].resample('W', how='count')


df
```

It gives a all Nan values for the column "week"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime
df['week'] = df.reset_index().apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.date(parse(x['index'])).strftime("%V"), axis=1).to_numpy()
```

output

```
           lead_date name week
2019-08-01  00:03:43    a   31
2019-08-01  00:00:00    b   31
2019-08-01  00:03:49    c   31
2019-08-31  23:42:04    a   35
2019-08-31  23:42:04    a   35
2019-08-31  23:42:04    c   35
2019-08-31  23:42:04    a   35
```

Comment: it is exacly what I need, but got this error    ```TypeError: ('Parser must be a string or character stream, not int', 'occurred at index 0')```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the `dt.week` attribute of the `datetime` to get the week.

```
df["lead_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["lead_date"])
df['week'] = df['lead_date'].dt.week
print(df)
```

**output**

```
            lead_date   name    week
0   2019-08-01 00:03:00     a   31
1   2019-08-01 00:00:00     b   31
2   2019-08-01 00:03:00     c   31
3   2019-08-31 23:42:00     a   35
4   2019-08-31 23:42:00     a   35
5   2019-08-31 23:42:00     c   35
6   2019-08-31 23:42:00     a   35
```

If your final goal is to group the dataframe by week, you don't need to create a separate column for that. You can just do something like `df.groupby(df['lead_date'].dt.week, as_index = False).count()`